# Is there any alternative of S_IRGRP and S_IROTH for windows?

Tags: c++

I wanted to give the permission of read to group and others, while read and write permission to Owner in Linux and Windows platform. Linux has macros S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH to do that. Does windows also have some macros as these or any other alternative?

I went through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/file-permission-constants?view=vs-2019. _S_IREAD seem to be one option. But it just says "Reading permitted". Not sure whether it will full fill my requirement

Comment: Windows has ACLs rather than the usual unix user-group-others model. You might need to use specific APIs like GetSecurityInfo, using handles from CreateFile rather than fopen etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/secauthz/finding-the-owner-of-a-file-object-in-c--

Comment: Also important: Windows does not have the notion of group ownership. The file owner is exclusively a user.  Note that group ownership is generally unintended anyway, so Unix and Linux systems generally define an exclusive group for each user.

Comment: @MSalters, if there is now notion of group ownership, then 'ls -l' shows three permission level in windows as well. What each individual area means?

Comment: @Shreyans: IIRC, Current User, Current User and Everyone. Yes, that's twice Current User.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MSalters. Is there any article/document i could read for further knowledge regarding the file structure used in windows?